# Calling Python script from another and passing List(sys.argv) as argument

Tags: python, execute

test1.py is the main script calling another script test2.py by passing the same argument list that has been passed to test1.py. I have done following but it reads the sys.argv list as string and parse into multiple arguments and also includes unnecessary [ and ,

```
test1.py
import os
import sys

argList=sys.argv[1:]

os.system('python another/location/test2.py %s'%(argList))
```

---

```
test2.py

import sys
print(sys.argv[1:])
```

---

```
Call test1.py
python test1.py -a -b -c
output: ['[-a,' ,'-b,', '-c]' ]
```

Please post if there is a better opti

Comment: When you do the string formatting, what is `argList` converted into? It's not quite what you expect. You want some way to format `argList` yourself...look into the `join` method of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
os.system('python another/location/test2.py %s' % ' '.join(argList))
```

if the arguments will contain no spaces themselves.

The second  program will output

```
['-a', '-b', '-c']
```

If your arguments can contain spaces, it might be best to quote them. Use `' '.join("'%s'" % arg.replace("'", "\\'") for arg in ArgList)`

Comment: Thank you, what is the use of join() ? will it append all List element with the separator ' '(space) ?

Comment: Indeed. `string.join(list)` will do `list[0] + string + list[1] + ...` (but it's better).

Answer (score 0):

in the case if you need to exit test1.py just after calling test2.py

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen( ('python', 'another/location/test2.py') + tuple( sys.argv[1:]) )
```